# How do I edit form data in a React function component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set a form field value with `useState`.

The `settings.values.apiKey` variable has a value, but the `textarea` element is empty.  What's wrong with my `useState`?

I tried to change `value={apiKey}` to `value={settings.values.apiKey}` and then the value is displayed, but then I can't change the value of the field. When I try to enter something, it always shows the original value.

App.js

```html
const App = () => {
    const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState(settings.values.apiKey)

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSettings = async () => {
            const settingsFromServer = await fetchSettings()
            setSettings(settingsFromServer)
        }

        getSettings()
    }, [])

    const fetchSettings = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/react-server/get.php')
        return await res.json()
    }

    const saveSettings = async (settings) => {
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Settings
                settings={settings}
                saveSettings={saveSettings}
            />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Settings.js:

```html
import { useState } from 'react';

const Settings = ({ settings, saveSettings }) => {
    const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState(settings.values.apiKey)

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        saveSettings({ apiKey})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form className='add-form' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <div className='form-control'>
                    <label>Api key</label>
                    <textarea
                        value={apiKey}
                        onChange={(e) => setApiKey(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>

                <input type='submit' value='Save settings' className='mt15' />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Settings
```

Comment: `App` should have `[settings, setSettings]` as its `useState` instead of `apiKey`, right?  Is that a copy/paste error or a mistake in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like by mistake you have used apiKey in App.js file as your state variable. It should be replaced by settings.

```
 const [settings, setSettings] = React.useState();
```

The above code would make `value={apiKey}` work properly for textarea in Settings.js file.
And, then onChange will also start working properly.

---

### *UPDATE*

In addition to the above mentioned error, in case `settings` props is undefined in `Settings.js`, this might cause your code to break at useState. So, instead put a check for settings values in useEffect and then set the value. The code would look like this or you can check the [codesandbox link here for working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-for-textarea-not-working-issue-sen57?file=/src/App.js).

**Settings.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Settings = ({ settings, saveSettings }) => {
  const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (settings?.values?.apiKey) {
      setApiKey(settings.values.apiKey);
    }
  }, [settings]);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    saveSettings({ apiKey });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="add-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-control">
          <label>Api key</label>
          <textarea
            value={apiKey}
            onChange={(e) => setApiKey(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save settings" className="mt15" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

**App.js**

```
const [settings, setSettings] = useState()
```

```
  const saveSettings = async (settings) => {
      setSettings(settings);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the result is the same.
Textarea still empty.

Comment: @lolalola I have updated my answer and added codesandbox link as well for working demo.